# Getting input from example : java calculate 10x20

Tags: java

I want my code to get input from console(not using scanner.in)
Example for after compiling, when written java calculate 10x20 it should give 200.
My code:

```
public class Calculate {


public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x= args[0];
        int y= args[1];
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(args[x]);
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(args[y]);
}
return n1*n2;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried the debuggers? They are useful. And this code won't even be correctly compiled, it has 4 errors in 9 lines according to my IDE.

Comment: @nier That is what I am asking, how to correct this code so I can compile it.

Comment: Did you really **read** those errors? For example, the error of `int x = args[0];` is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int". I think it's obvious enough though. If you really don't know what does that error mean, you should show us you have read these errors, and tell us which part of the errors you don't know, then we can answer to your specific question.

Comment: So you run your code using `java -jar Calculate.jar 10x20`? Or `java -jar Calculate.jar 10 20`? If the first, you'll have to add a split for `x` and only use the `args[0]`. Also, in your current code you'll have an error at `int x = args[0];` since `args[0]` is a String. You'll have to use `int n1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` directly, instead of using the `int x = ..`

Comment: How do you want the result to appear?  Just have it printed on standard output?

Comment: @Nier since I am not using any debuggers, I only see the errors in terminal. Nevermind, solved it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're passing the input gives you only one argument. `10x20` is a single string argument. To calculate the result you have to do something like this.

```
public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] operands = args[0].split("x");
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(operands[1]);
        System.out.println(n1*n2);
    }
}
```

You have to check for valid arguments or you should pass the arguments correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The args is a string array . So args[0] and args[1] have to be parsed into int . And you have written return in main which always returns void . Below code works fine .

public class Calculate {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println(x * y);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What'i wrong here:

`args` is an array of String so `args[0]` and  `args[1]`should be Strings

```
String x= args[0];
String y= args[1];
```

The correct way to convert a String to int is :

```
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

The main method has  `void`  has return type so in cannot return a value.

Putting all together you should have something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x= args[0];
    String y= args[1];
    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(y);
    int result = n1*n2;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

> To run this code you must call `java calculate 10 20` instead of `java calculate 10x20`

If you really want to run it with `java calculate 10x20` you already have a nice answer.